# Mac OSX code . command does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

First of all happy new year to all, I am trying to set Visual Studio Code to start from terminal and using the instructions from VS Code site but editing ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile file with following command does not work out.

```
function code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*; }
```

So what could be the problem?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh your bash_profile after making changes.

`. ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

just paste following command to terminal and return. no need to close terminal or restart

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. After editing the bash_profile. We need to reset the machine to make changes effective

Comment: Just close the terminal and reopen it, no need to restart the machine.